# ‘We curled through the library’?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, slang

Is there a word similar in sound to 'curl' or 'furl' or a connotation of either that applies in a sentence like “we *curled* through the entire library” to imply searching or something of the like?

I was not able to find a similar definition by Oxford, so is it that this is slang? Please respond if you recognize it.

Comment: Never heard of that usage, curled, but it sounds deliciously accurate. You move along and then you tun to the left or the right every now and then.

Comment: Furrowed? . . .

Comment: Just a rhyme or maybe cockney rhyming slang?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The verb **curl** is not uncommon, but its use in the given sentence is non-standard.

Perhaps

- We trawled [through] the entire library, trying to find a reference to Nicholas Flamel

is what OP has in mind:

> **trawl** [verb] 5. [transitive; intransitive when often coupled with 'through']   [Chiefly British]
>
> to make a thorough search (of)

[[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/trawl)] [adjusted]

Though the metaphorical sense of 'trawl [through]' is usually used with metaphorical locations, corpora:

> - *We trawled the British Library archives, and found these incredible musical pictures*

[[Classic fm: Discover Music](https://www.classicfm.com/discover-music/latest/british-library-pictures/bab-ballads/)]

........................

The verb **curl** itself (considering just intransitive usages) is a (not-overly-close) synonym of *meander*, and like *meander* may be (a) clearly *stative*, often with a locative prepositional phrase

> - *The road curled around the side of the hill*  ['meander' adds wiggliness]

[[Wordhelp](https://www.wordhelp.com/parts-of-speech/english/?q=curled)]

(b) clearly *dynamic*, often with a directional prepositional phrase, or adverb (/resultative adjective?)

> - *Peterson's free-kick curled just wide* ['meander' not usable here; 'curl' can be (and here is) swifter and single-curve]

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/curl)]

or (c) indeterminate

> - *The air was fresh and crisp, and little smoke-blue mists curled through the valleys* [probably movement involved here, so dynamic default; 'meander' works for this]

[[Wordhelp](https://www.wordhelp.com/parts-of-speech/english/?q=curled)]

> - *her fingers curled round the microphone* [state or event both possible; 'meander' rather quirky here]

[[Oxford Languages](https://www.google.com/search?q=curl+meaning&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB973GB973&oq=curl+meaning&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i64j0i67i650l2j0i512l4.2049943793j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)]

However, examples with a volitional (sentient) agent or a vehicle (car, bike) as subject are rare on the internet (and indeed [Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+curled+through%2Cthe+car+curled+through&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) show flatlines for 'we curled through' and 'the car curled through')

That said, the occasional example can be found on the internet, for instance

> - *We curled through a rural residential area where any one of the horses grazing along the road were worth way more than my new used
>   Subaru Outback*

[[New Hampshire Magazine](https://www.nhmagazine.com/goodbye-to-the-bee-3/)]

> - *Our road trips took us on adventures through read-aloud books as we curled through the mountains.*

[[Terry Lewis; Tallahassee Democrat](https://eu.tallahassee.com/story/entertainment/2022/06/03/childrens-book-i-am-inspired-accentuates-positive/7495987001/)]

> - *The car curled around the track's tight corners, writhed past the fast bends as Kimi explored its capabilities before coiling back in
>   the ...*

[[Sauber Group](https://www.sauber-group.com/motorsport/f1-news/the-snakes-new-skin-alfa-romeo-racing-orlen-c39-completes-shakedown-in-iconic-snakeskin-livery/)]

........................

In summary, 'curl [through]' is sometimes used for 'wind one's [/its] way through', but rarely of people. It does not give any sense of urgency (like 'meander', quite the opposite) and certainly does not hint at a search. Its use here, while not ungrammatical, would verge on the bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

It actually just came back to me that it really is a slang phrase where I'm from (Jamaica), connoting not 'searching' but a sort of general 'racing through'

thanks a lot for the help and apologies for the misunderstanding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *What* is the phrase? *Curl, furl, hurl, whirl* or something different?

Comment: *birl* is Scottish slang for spin, twirl, or by extension try (c.f. give it a spin). Might have been carried along with Scottish migrants; a lot of Scots worked on Caribbean plantations.

Comment: @StuartF That's one I hadn't thought of! Perhaps it could even be *skirl...*

Answer (score -1):

If the intended implication is that all the pages in the library were turned, then this might be a place for [**'leaf through'**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leaf_through):

"we leafed through the entire library".

However, most dictionary definitions mention a connotation of skimming, or a superficial search, which you may not want.

Comment: It would be very nice if a downvote was accompanied by a brief explanation, so I don't make the same sort of mistake again, or can cease following the site.